# rpy2 on Windows 10 Jupyter notebook got 0x7e

Tags: python, r, rpy2

On my windows 10, Like [Jupyter OSError 0x7e when loading rpy2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61624749/jupyter-oserror-0x7e-when-loading-rpy2) error.

I'l show rpy2.situation as follows.

rpy2 version:
3.3.5
Python version:
3.7.7 (default, May  6 2020, 11:45:54) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Looking for R's HOME:
Environment variable R_HOME: None
InstallPath in the registry: C:\Program Files\Microsoft\ML Server\R_SERVER
Environment variable R_USER: None
Environment variable R_LIBS_USER: None
R version:
In the PATH: None
Loading R library from rpy2: cannot load library 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\ML Server\R_SERVER\bin\x64\R.dll': error 0x7e
Additional directories to load R packages from:
None
C extension compilation:
include:
['C:/PROGRA~1/MIE74D~1/MLSERV~1/R_SERVER/include', 'C:/PROGRA~1/MIE74D~1/MLSERV~1/R_SERVER/include/x64']
libraries:
['R', 'm']
library_dirs:
['C:/PROGRA~1/MIE74D~1/MLSERV~1/R_SERVER/bin/x64']
extra_compile_args:
[]
extra_link_args:
[]

Comment: Could you clarify what have you tried and what is the issue? The question is not well written, I recommend you to read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section and formulate and format your question in better manner.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OSError: cannot load library 'C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.2\bin\x64\R.dll': error 0x7e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63863449/oserror-cannot-load-library-c-program-files-r-r-4-0-2-bin-x64-r-dll-error-0)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working solution:

```
import os
os.environ["R_HOME"] = r"D:\Install\R\R-3.6.1"
os.environ["PATH"]   = r"D:\Install\R\R-3.6.1\bin\x64" + ";" + os.environ["PATH"]
import rpy2
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri, packages
pandas2ri.activate()
stats = packages.importr('stats')
```