# OSError: cannot load library 'C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.2\bin\x64\R.dll': error 0x7e

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, rpy2

I am trying to import the rpy2 library into a Jupyter Notebook but I cannot get past this error.

The PATH 'C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.2\bin\x64' has been added.

This is the only version of R installed on my computer. I have completely uninstalled and reinstalled R/Rstudio/Anaconda with no luck.

Here is the full error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-098f0d39b3a3> in <module>
----> 1 from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\__init__.py in <module>
     14 from functools import partial
     15 import types
---> 16 import rpy2.rinterface as rinterface
     17 import rpy2.rlike.container as rlc
     18 

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\rpy2\rinterface.py in <module>
      4 import typing
      5 from typing import Union
----> 6 from rpy2.rinterface_lib import openrlib
      7 import rpy2.rinterface_lib._rinterface_capi as _rinterface
      8 import rpy2.rinterface_lib.embedded as embedded

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\rpy2\rinterface_lib\openrlib.py in <module>
     42     rlib = _rinterface_cffi.lib
     43 else:
---> 44     rlib = _dlopen_rlib(R_HOME)
     45 
     46 

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\rpy2\rinterface_lib\openrlib.py in _dlopen_rlib(r_home)
     35         raise ValueError('The library path cannot be None.')
     36     else:
---> 37         rlib = ffi.dlopen(lib_path)
     38     return rlib
     39 

OSError: cannot load library 'C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.2\bin\x64\R.dll': error 0x7e
```

edit:

Here is the code I run to import rpy2 library:

```
from rpy2.robjects import r, pandas2ri
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail? What exactly triggered the error message?

Comment: Please post code that raises error. Error message alone is not helpful.

Comment: I have supplied the code I use to import the rpy2 library.

Comment: Did you try restarting the kernel or jupyter server?

Comment: I have restarted the kernel, server, and my computer. The error persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1 - Windows + IDE

For those **not** using Anaconda, add the following in Windows' environment variables PATH:

`C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.3\bin\x64`

Your R version may differ from "R-4.0.3"

#### 2 - Anaconda

Otherwise, check Grayson Felt's reply:

> [I found a solution here.](https://anaconda.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023857134-Setting-up-rpy2-on-Windows)
>
> Adding the PATH
>
> > C:\Users\username\Anaconda2;C:\Users\username\Anaconda2\Scripts;C:\Users\username\Anaconda2\Library\bin;C:\Users\username\Anaconda2\Library\mingw-w64\lib;C:\Users\username\Anaconda2\Library\mingw-w64\bin
>
> and subsequently restarting Anaconda fixed the issue.

#### 3 - Code header Windows basic

Alternatively, following Bruno's suggestion (and being more sohpisticated):

```
try:
    import rpy2.robjects as robjects
except OSError as e:
    try:
        import os
        import platform
        if ('Windows', 'Microsoft') in platform.system():
            os.environ["R_HOME"] = 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.3/bin/x64'  # Your R version here 'R-4.0.3'
            os.environ["PATH"] = "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.3/bin/x64" + ";" + os.environ["PATH"]
        import rpy2.robjects as robjects
    except OSError:
        raise(e)
```

This code won't be effective for non-Windows platform.
Also adjustments may be necessary for different R versions.
If it gets more complicated than this, you should probably just go for solutions 1 or 2.

***NOTE***: You may also face this issue if your Python and R versions are in different architechtures (x86 vs x64)

Answer (score 7):

Here is my working solution:

```
import os
os.environ["R_HOME"] = r"D:\Install\R\R-3.6.1"
os.environ["PATH"]   = r"D:\Install\R\R-3.6.1\bin\x64" + ";" + os.environ["PATH"]
import rpy2
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri, packages
pandas2ri.activate()
stats = packages.importr('stats')
```

Comment: what is the ''r"D:\Install\R\R-3.6.1"  referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Import it on top, before importing r packages.

```
import os
os.environ["R_HOME"] = r"C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.2.1" 
os.environ["PATH"] = r"C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.2.1\\bin\\x64" + ";" + 
    os.environ["R_HOME"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    import rpy2.robjects as robjects

except OSError as e:

    try:
        import os
        import platform
        if 'Windows' in platform.system():
            os.environ["R_HOME"] = 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.1'
            os.environ["PATH"] = "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.1/bin/x64;" + os.environ["PATH"]
        import rpy2.robjects as robjects
    except OSError:
        raise e
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The other answers work for Python < 3.8 but since 3.8, setting PATH and other environmental variables using os.environ() stopped working. For security reasons, environmental paths no longer resolves DLLs. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69816601/1297830) has more details.

Instead, include the DLL path explicitly before loading rpy2:

```py
import os
os.add_dll_directory(r"path_to_R/bin/x64/")  # E.g., "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.3.1/bin/x64"
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
```

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre: I've deleted the replies to other posts and marked them as duplicates of this one. However, I can't undelete my answer (which is the only one answer works on python >=3.8), so I posted this new one.