# pymer4 import error "cannot load library '\R\R-4.1.0\bin\x64\R.dll': error 0x7e"

Tags: python, r, conda, spyder

I am trying to use pymer4 to run linear mixed models in python (in Spyder).

I installed via conda according to the following instructions:
https://eshinjolly.com/pymer4/installation.html

However, when I run:

```
import pymer4
```

I get the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\rinterface_lib\openrlib.py", line 37, in _dlopen_rlib
    rlib = ffi.dlopen(lib_path)

OSError: cannot load library '\R\R-4.1.0\bin\x64\R.dll': error 0x7e
```

In contrast, rpy2 works fine:

```
import rpy2
```

I have already tried going to control panel > system preferences > advanced system settings > enviornment variables > system variables > path > and making sure the path to R ("C:\Users\username\R\R-4.1.0\bin\x64") is there.

When I try this solution ([OSError: cannot load library 'C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.2\bin\x64\R.dll': error 0x7e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63863449/oserror-cannot-load-library-c-program-files-r-r-4-0-2-bin-x64-r-dll-error-0)), the kernel crashes and shows "fatal error unable to open base package":

```
import os
os.environ["R_HOME"] = r"C:\Users\username\R\R-4.1.0"
os.environ["PATH"]   = r"C:\Users\username\R\R-4.1.0\bin\x64" + ";" + os.environ["PATH"]
import pymer4
```

It's important to note I have used R and RStudio before on this computer so there may be confusion with that.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Try `os.add_dll_directory(r"path_to_R/bin/x64/")` before importing. See more [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78128188/1297830)