# Can't Run rpy2 library in VSCode (error 0x7e)

Tags: python, r, dll, subprocess, rpy2

I really new to this field, so I have to explore some of new feature in Vscode. I have been tried to run rscript on python intrepeter. But it likely to not resolve many problem. First is a testing code

```
from rpy2 import robjects 
pi = robjects.r['pi'] 
pi
```

On terminal, i get this statement:

```
rpy2\rinterface_lib\openrlib.py", line 51, in _dlopen_rlib
    rlib = ffi.dlopen(lib_path)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: cannot load library 'C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.1\bin\x64\R.dll': error 0x7e
```

I have tried another solution to open R Script with subprocess function, but it having another trouble.

```
retcode = subprocess.call(["C:/Users/X/.vscode-R/RScript", "Testing_F.r"])              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\subprocess.py", line 389, in call     
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Any people dealing with same issues with rpy2? How i can deal with it?

I have tried this on Colab, then it works as without dealing some error.

Comment: Does `R.dll` exist on that path?

Comment: Sure.. it exist

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OSError: cannot load library 'C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.2\bin\x64\R.dll': error 0x7e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63863449/oserror-cannot-load-library-c-program-files-r-r-4-0-2-bin-x64-r-dll-error-0)