# Setting up rpy2

Tags: python, rpy2

Im trying to run rpy2 version 3.5.14 on python version 3.10.11 with R version 4.3.2 installed
I have looked up on some fixes for the error 0x7e "cannot load library" but somehow those fixes wont do it.

My code in VScode which should be solving the problem looks like this:

```
try:
    import rpy2.robjects as robjects
except OSError as e:
    try:
        import os
        import platform
        if ('Windows') in platform.system():
            os.environ["R_HOME"] = 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.3.2/bin/x64'  # Your R version here
            os.environ["PATH"] = "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.3.2/bin/x64" + ";" + os.environ["PATH"]
            #os.environ["PATH"] = 'C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.3.2\\bin\\x64\\R.dll' + ";" + os.environ["PATH"]
        import rpy2.robjects as robjects
    except OSError:
        raise(e)
```

And the error message is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\Codes\GSADF\rpy2_test.py", line 13, in <module>
    raise(e)
  File "E:\Python\Codes\GSADF\rpy2_test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import rpy2.robjects as robjects
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    import rpy2.rinterface as rinterface
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\rpy2\rinterface.py", line 19, in <module>
    from rpy2.rinterface_lib import openrlib
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\rpy2\rinterface_lib\openrlib.py", line 58, in <module>
    rlib = _dlopen_rlib(R_HOME)
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\rpy2\rinterface_lib\openrlib.py", line 51, in _dlopen_rlib
    rlib = ffi.dlopen(lib_path)
OSError: cannot load library 'C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.2\bin\x64\R.dll': error 0x7e
```

Im sitting for days now and somehow nothing is fixing the issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: Error 0x7e is "module not found".  You're sure R.DLL exists at that location?  R probably needs other DLLs as well.  Is there a batch file to set up R's environment?

Comment: r.dll is located at the same path "C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.2\bin\x64", there is no batch file present, because I have reinstalled R on the same drive as Python

Comment: According to the documentation, rpy2 is not officially supported on Windows, although some people have made it work.  Do you have a Windows SDK?  My guess is you'll need to check the imports for R.DLL and see which library is missing.

Comment: Thanks for your help tim, i used dependency walker cause windows SDK wasn't working and got a ton of missing files ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OSError: cannot load library 'C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.2\bin\x64\R.dll': error 0x7e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63863449/oserror-cannot-load-library-c-program-files-r-r-4-0-2-bin-x64-r-dll-error-0)